# What is this sign is called and how to do it in Latex

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

[image]

Can someone please tell me what is `|maximum` is called in math terms and how to do it in latex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your equation is usual (considering SI standards) writen as:

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode = symbol}

\begin{document}
\[
S = \left.\frac{dV_{0}}{dt}\right|_{\max}    \quad\si{\volt\per\micro\second}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]